# Rails: Rendering Models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

I can think of a million not-so-automatic ways to render a model in Rails, but I'm wondering if there's some built-in way to do it. I'd like to be able to this

```
<%=@thing -%>
```

obviously with partials you can do it (I mean, calling render :partial), but I'm wondering if there's some standard way to **associate** views with models.

[Thanks in advance, weppos, for fixing the tags on this question :)]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you pass a model directly to [render](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000658) it will attempt to render a partial for it.

```
<%= render @thing %>
```

That is the same as.

```
<%= render :partial => 'things/thing', :object => @thing %>
```

If you pass an array of models...

```
<%= render @things %>
```

It will render the `_thing` partial for each as if you did this.

```
<%= render :partial => 'things/thing', :collection => @things %>
```

Note: this requires Rails 2.3. If you have earlier versions of Rails you'll need to use the :partial option to do the same thing.

```
<%= render :partial => @thing %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `to_s` method in your model to return the representation that you want, although this isn't necessarily desirable because then your model contains presentation concerns that correctly belong in your view.

Besides, `to_s` is really meant to return a short, string representation of your model useful for debugging purposes etc.

Comment: Exactly. I've been adding a .to_html on the model, but that's the TOTALLY wrong place for view code. Which you mention. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You’re not coming from [Seaside](http://www.seaside.st/) are you? :)  (I ask because this is exactly how things work there, where each model/renderable object knows how to render itself, and that’s how you lay the page out.)

In regards to your actual question, the standard way to do it is by rendering a partial that you feed your @thing to. (i.e. you’re right on the money about the partials, and that’s the way views are typically associated with models.)

Comment: Nope, Seaside for me is just a place on the Jersey short. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seaside_Heights,_New_Jersey

Comment: This way of thinking is very OO, though, and that's typical of smalltalk.