# rendering two instance variables with one partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the index file of a Rails to-do app (code from Railscast), it lists out the incomplete and complete tasks that were assigned to instance variables in the tasks controller. Notice how it calls render @incomplete_tasks and render @complete_tasks, whereas the partial is only called

```
_task.html.erb
```

It appears this one partial is used for rendering both incomplete and complete tasks. Is Rails able to ignore the first half of the instance variables (ie. @incomplete and @complete) to use the one partial for rendering both?

controller

```
 def index
    if current_user
      @incomplete_tasks = current_user.tasks.where(complete: false)
      @complete_tasks = current_user.tasks.where(complete: true)
    end
  end
```

Index

```
<% if @incomplete_tasks.empty? && @complete_tasks.empty? %>
    <p>Currently no tasks. Add one above.</p>
  <% else %>
    <h2>Incomplete Tasks</h2>
    <div class="tasks" id="incomplete_tasks">
      <%= render @incomplete_tasks %>
    </div>

    <h2>Complete Tasks</h2>
    <div class="tasks" id="complete_tasks">
      <%= render @complete_tasks %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**_task.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for task, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :complete %>
  <%= f.label :complete, task.name %>
  <%= link_to "(remove)", task, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you lost me on "Is Rails able to ignore the first half of the instance variable". can you explain that a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So rails looks at the model objects to determine which partial to use when you use that kind of syntax. In both cases the instance variables contain tasks so rails knows to use the _task partial.

Comment: So the name of the instance variable doesn't matter as long as it ends in the name of the model, _tasks in this case?

Comment: or the name of the variable doesn't matter at all when rendering

Comment: Yeah unless you pass the options hash declaring which partial to use. This is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer of @ryanb, see it here : [Rails: Rendering Models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260682/rails-rendering-models)

If you pass a model directly to [render](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000658) it will attempt to render a partial for it.

```
<%= render @thing %>
```

That is the same as.

```
<%= render :partial => 'things/thing', :object => @thing %>
```

If you pass an array of models...

```
<%= render @things %>
```

It will render the `_thing` partial for each as if you did this.

```
<%= render :partial => 'things/thing', :collection => @things %>
```

Note: this requires Rails 2.3. If you have earlier versions of Rails you'll need to use the :partial option to do the same thing.

```
<%= render :partial => @thing %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is full answer on this question.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

2.2.13 Avoiding Double Render Errors